# Monitor file copy during compilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

I used to have in my projects some post build events and after build events,
which I used in order to copy files.
I also had CopyLocal = true.

I was deleting all the post build and after build events and copylocal is now equal to false.
There are some dll files which still their way to the bin folder....

how can I detect who copied those files?

thanks.

Comment: disabling components one-by-one?

Comment: I have 205 components :)

Comment: look for the copied filename in the *.csproj files.

Comment: I did it, I ran notepad++ and I didn't find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try building from a Visual Studio command prompt and [saving a verbose log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470), so you can search for the names of the copied files and find out which project is copying them:

```
msbuild <solution name> /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MyLog.log;verbosity=diagnostic
```

This should get you some results even if the files aren't mentioned by name in the .csproj files.